# how do I provide an api key in a safe way?

Tags: powershell

Here's something I hadn't given much thought: when I `Publish-Module`, I provide an API key. That ends up in my command history. `Clear-History` doesn't work, I have to delete the file storing the history (or delete a specific line). I'd rather not do that.

Is there a better way to supply an api key safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from reading it from a file, you could treat it like a password.

```
$secureinput = Read-host -Prompt "Enter the API key" -AsSecureString

$plaintext = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("", $secureinput).Password
```